# create function signature that return both true and false while providing details upon failure

Tags: c++, return-value

The short version of this question is how to implement a single function that return both `true` and `false` while providing details upon failure (`false`)?

Say I want to create static function `remove()` that will get a path as a `string` and remove it from the file system.
Assuming remove operation may cause some unexpected errors, I'd like to be able to return a status.

**Version 1**

```
static bool remove( const string& path );
```

This will return `true` if path was removed and `false` otherwise.
But what if I need more details regarding the failure of the remove process?

**Version 2**

```
static void remove( const string& path );
```

This function now **throw** some `exception` on failure which will basically return the reason why remove process failed. This mandates each caller to use `try-catch` when calling this function which can be a bit annoying and ugly if you don't care about the result.

I trying to generate a clean signature that will allow me to combine both versions into a single one.
`remove` function is just one of many static utility functions so I'd like to avoid having to leave both versions (even though they are not overrideable at the moment).

**Suggestion 1:**

```
static bool remove( const string& path, bool throw_on_fail );
```

Now the caller can alternate both versions of the function by passing a boolean flag.
I don't like this suggestion. As I said `remove` function is just one of many static utility functions. I don't think adding boolean argument for each function is such a good idea.

**Suggestion 2:**

```
static EResultCode remove( const string& path );
```

Here we have an `enum` as the result.
This one is a bit better but I can already see such bugs as the next `if` statement `if remove("f1")`. getting int value 4 from `remove()` does not imply success.

**Suggestion 3:**

```
static Result remove( const string& path );
```

Here we have a class `Result` that will contain both Boolean and detailed description.
This seems like an overkill to me.

#### Question

I looked at the API of common `c++` libraries interface, [wx](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_filefunctions.html) & [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html). could not find overwhelming insights there.

I'm trying to come up with a generic signature for all those functions. which way would you go?

Comment: Can you give more details as to why suggestion 3 is overkill?

Comment: I can't understand why members here are so quick to flag this question as opinion based.

Comment: It seems to me, that if you want to remove something from the file system, and that operation fails, that would be an _exceptional_ case.  This is `C++` after all, just use an exception for failure and bake in all the details you want.

Comment: @VaughnCato it seems like an overkill to me since all callers of `remove()` need to be familiar with `Result` interface in order to retrieve a simple boolean value. some callers just need true and false. I don't know, perhaps my argument is senseless now that I think about it.

Comment: @Chad `remove()` is not the only function. In addition, what concern me is that on that approach "it mandates each caller to use try-catch when calling this function which can be a bit annoying and ugly if you don't care about the result."

Comment: In that case, (see my answer below) provide an override that takes the error code to be populated by reference.  This is similar to how the `boost::asio` API is implemented (though it provides overloads both for taking in an error code and for throwing exceptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely go with the Result class approach.

Ignoring the question of whether exceptions are the right tool to handle a file-not-found error in the first place, an additional bool parameter to enable or disable them will make client code less readable because of all the true and false arguments whose meaning is completely unclear unless the reader consults remove()'s documentation or at least its signature:

```
remove("file.txt", true); // what's true?!
```

I would also refrain from error references. It is so frustrating when you (the function's client) are forced to use additional local variables which you might not even need later on. Very C++-unlike. This approach will eventually result in a lot of client code like this:

```
Error dummy;
remove("file.txt", dummy);
```

The Result class approach means clients will have to type a bit more *if* they need to know the details of an error, but their code will become much clearer and readable as a result of it. Your concern that this may put an additional burden on clients seems unfounded, at least if I imagine myself as the client of remove() :)

Comment: That's a nice answer. Assuming we have no other way to attack this, I also like `suggestion 3` better.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct status {
    std::string msg;
    bool success;

    status(): success(true) {}
    status(std::string msg_): success(false), msg(msg_) {}

    explicit operator bool() const { return success; }

};

static status const success;

status func1() { return true; }
status func2() { return success; }
status func3() { return status("something went wrong); }

if (func1()) { std::cout << "success!" << std::endl; }
if (func1().success) { std::cout << "success!" << std::endl; }

auto rc = func3();
if (!rc) { std::cout << "error" << rc.msg << std::endl; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function `remove()`, and that functions purpose is to *remove* things from the file system, we should expect it to work in the normal case.

In the case where is can't work for some reason (there are a multitude of reasons it could fail) we should treat that as an exception to the normal working case.

I would suggest:

```
void remove() {...}
```

And calling it:

```
try
{
   remove("/home/olduser");
}
catch(std::runtime_error& e)
{
   std::cerr << "Failed to remove: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

Exceptions are part of the language for a reason, *use them*.

You said you looked to `boost` (and others) for inspiration.  Look at the implementation of `boost::asio`.  Almost all of the functions there have two overloads, one that takes an error code to report *into*, and one that has the same behavior but simply throws the error code as an exception in the case of failure.

Providing *both* may be overkill.  My preference is to rely on exception handling, as it was specifically designed for handling these types of situations.

Comment: It depends on the requirements.  If the requirements are simply that there is no file named `filename` after the function, then failure is exceptional, and can be treated as an exception.  If the requirements are that the function fail if there is no file by that name to begin with, and the function name comes from the user... There's nothing exceptional about a user mistyping a filename.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in one case is have the function return a `char
const*`, with a `nullptr` for success, and the error message for
failure.  Still, in this case, the functions were `extern "C"`,
so I didn't have nearly as many alternatives.  In C++, I'd
probably define a class, and return it.  The class could have an
implicit conversion to `bool` if you wanted, but I'm not
convinced that it's a good idea; I'd have a `succeeded` function
which returned `bool`: it's a lot clearer.

Note that even in this case, you'll have to store the return
value into a local variable, in order to have the additional
information still present after you've detected the failure; you
cannot simply write:

```
if ( remove( path ) ) {
    //  error
} else {
    //  success
}
```

but need to write:

```
Results results = remove( path );
if ( !results ) {
    //  error, do something with results.message()
} else {
    //  success
}
```

Also rather painful, almost as much as a try catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
static bool remove( const string& path, tStatus& myStatus );
```

And define tStatus as whatever type you want to return errors as.  Could be as simple as `typedef int tStatus;`

Comment: `tStatus` can be also contain a value to indicate success. no need to return bool as well. so we are back in `suggestion 2`

Comment: Well, I thought you wanted to return a bool so you could more easily do statements like `if(!function(foo, bar, status)) return status;`

And if your error reason structure ends up being a larger class that contains strings, suggestion 2 is going to not work as well.

Comment: well, I do want that but not at the expense of having a redundancy in the return value.

Comment: Right.  You could just return void then and only check the status.  It's a design pattern I've seen a lot of, actually.  Similar to the Error Cluster in LabVIEW code, if you've used that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also let the function return a bool, and among the parameters you pass a reference to a structure that may contain the reason. Like this:

```
bool remove(const string& path, FailReason* fr){
  //if the FailReason is a null pointer we don't fill it
  If(fr != 0);
}
```

You can pass null in the fail struct

Comment: NULL references aren't a defined c++.  I think you meant to use a pointer?

Comment: Yeah, my head is obviously a little messed up...

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
static bool remove(const string& path, std::nothrow_t);
static void remove(const string& path);
```